# Web page is not loaded after activation

Tags: php, redirect, cookies

If users use the registration form to register, by going directly to the registration page , then they receive an e-mail with an activation link, and when they click on it, the index page of the logged-in section is loaded. This works fine.

But in the case where the (non-registered) user goes to the registration page by clicking a link to a [restricted page](http://www.studyhood.com/english/translation_second.php?tr_price=50&tr_days=3&tr_words=500&tr_fr=Arabic&tr_it=English&tr_type=Regular), the e-mail activation link redirects to [here](http://www.studyhood.com/http:/www.studyhood.com/english/translation_second.php?tr_price=28&tr_days=3&tr_words=56&tr_fr=Azerbaijani&tr_it=English&tr_type=Regular). 
Because of that additional http://www.studyhood.com inserted at the beginning of the URL, the browser returns an error message.

Finally, if the user logs in (not registers) after clicking on the link to the restricted page, everything is again fine, since she is taken to translation_second.php without any problem.

Comment: Could you show us some code?

Comment: I have thought of the following solution: if the user clicks on the Register button of the registration form, then the cookies of my web site to be cleared. What do you think, and how can I do it? I have understood that the link to the restricted page http://www.studyhood.com/english/translation_second.php?tr_price=50&tr_days=3&tr_words=500&tr_fr=Arabic&tr_it=English&tr_type=Regular  with all these parameter values is stored as a cookie.

Comment: I made it work! Here is what I did, and please tell me what you think.
When one submits the registration form, the browser returns automatically a confirmation page. I have used the following php code, in the confirmation page, to delete the cookies from my domain:
<?php
// unset cookies
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE'])) {
    $cookies = explode(';', $_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']);
    foreach($cookies as $cookie) {
        $parts = explode('=', $cookie);
        $name = trim($parts[0]);
        setcookie($name, '', time()-1000);
        setcookie($name, '', time()-1000, '/');
    }
}
?>